# How to hide print button while printing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to print the page on button click without opening a new tab.

I have a following lines of code that does the job for me.

```
function PrintDiv() {    
    var contents = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML;
    var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
    frame1.name = "frame1";
    frame1.style.position = "absolute";
    frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
    document.body.appendChild(frame1);
    var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
    frameDoc.document.open();
    frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
    frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
    frameDoc.document.write(contents);
    frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
    frameDoc.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.frames["frame1"].focus();
        window.frames["frame1"].print();
        document.body.removeChild(frame1);
    }, 500);

    return false;
}
```

I got a print button inside the div with id wrapper

```
<div id="button-container">
    <a href="#" id="PrintDiv" class="btn btn-success btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>Print</a>
</div>
```

My problem is I am not being able to hide the print button while printing.

I have tried following lines to hide but its not working in my case.

```
$('#PrintDiv').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Comment: Last line is jquery,do you have jquery added?

Comment: you can disable button

Comment: I think it's easier if you just assign a CSS print rule to hide hit.

Comment: @Mihai, yes i have added

Answer (score 7):

You need to have a print based CSS style rule - you can also set other print based rules - such as document size, background color , image specs etc:

```
@media print {
   #button-container{
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes i have tried this one as well. But i dont know why its not working

Comment: my guess is that you are recreating the page content in that iframe and as such you are replicating the id - this rule is based arount the 1 id so the replicated content with the duplicate id will not be affected - remember ids have to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use below methods,

```
$('#PrintDiv').hide();
```

or

```
$('#PrintDiv').prop('disabled', 'true');
```

or

```
 @media print{
    #PrintDiv{
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work, because the document is at the `print media-query` and does not use the affected styles.

Comment: Right now understood what you want to do.. use `print` query as others suggested but with `!important`. updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need `@media print` in you css. Just add this at your bottom ofyour CSS file,

```
@media print {
    #print {display: none;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a media query to hide when printing

```
@media print {
   #button-container{
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <div id="button-container">
     <a href="#" id="PrintDiv" class="btn btn-success btn-primary" style="visibility:block;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"n aria-hidden="true"></span>Print</a> </div>
```

```js
document.getElementById('PrintDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

document.getElementById('PrintDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';